# Execute [code-execution]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[code-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-execution) has no followers and only 27 questions tagged. In my opinion nearly all posts on Stack Overflow are about executing code, so I think this tag should be removed.

In addition, there is also [execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution), with 891 questions and only one follower. I am not sure whether there will be situations where this tag would be appropriate so I would like to discuss whether this tag should be kept. However, provided that this tag exists, this means that [code-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-execution) is even more unnecessary.

Besides, there is also [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execute), with 2 followers and 761 questions. Its tag wiki says the following:

> In many dialects of SQL, the execute statement is used to invoke a stored procedure.

However, it appears that this tag is misused in a lot of questions. There are only 60 questions tagged with both [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execute). Should we create a new tag [sql-execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-execute), retag these 60 questions, and remove [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execute) as well?

I therefore request [code-execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-execution) to be removed, and would like to discuss if [execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution) and [execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execute) is worth keeping.

Comment: I think code execution is ambiguous, since this whole site is about writing code that works.

Comment: You should keep this discussion to the burnination of code-execution and not ask about the other tags here. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/288789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag is gone. It was roomba'd last night.

[image]