# Let's perform an [execution]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/execution) does not add anything to posts. Its a very meta tag. All code should execute. I can't think of why the language, library, framework or tag wouldn't help.

Related, but not a dupe: [Execute [code-execution]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295644/execute-code-execution)

Comment: Admit it, you only suggested this burnination for its pun potential!

Comment: According its description it seems to be about program executions. It's not a very detailed description, so I'm thinking about `CreateProcess()`, `ShellExecute()`, `Process.Start()` and similar. If that were the case, it might narrow the scope of questions a bit. In that case, someone could be an expert in that, e.g. if he understood the internals of the operating system and the various ways a process can be started and problems that may occur.

Comment: Related: [Burninate/retag the execute tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253435/burninate-retag-the-execute-tag)

Comment: It's not a meta tag, but it is a useless tag because execution is what programs are designed to do, therefore it applies to all programming questions.  Even the "tools commonly used by programmers" themselves are executed.

Comment: I don't find it an useful tag but It does not always apply to questions about data structures, file formats, documentation or compilation errors.

Comment: Could we consider a [public] execution?

Comment: I don't want pseudo-code to be executed though

Answer (score 2):

Nuke it from orbit.

On topic: yes but that must not be allowed to save it.

Clear: Either no or 2/3 of the questions on SO get it.

Useful. No.

Meaningful: So the code compiled (if interpreted, syntax checked). We normally don't want questions about code that doesn't compile.